# An effective way to display multiple labels

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I am looking for an effective, quick way to show multiple labels in a quick fashion.  What's a good way to do this other than replacing all the .text properties of the labels one after another?  It is my understanding that whenever you update a .text property the UI has to be repainted which will add to latency if you have 50+ controls to update.

I know threading is an option but when I tried this I didn't see much of a difference as I wasn't able to load 2 labels at once, I still had to wait for the UI thread before the labels would update.  What other ways are there to effectively load 50+ labels quickly?  The way it is now takes quite awhile(3-4s) and I feel this could be lowered.  The information is being taken from a backend system so I don't have the option for datasets/etc.

Comment: Can you please post your code? 3-4s sounds too slow for 50 labels.

Comment: Are you saying the backend takes 3-4 seconds to supply the data for the labels?

Comment: I'm Not able to post the code, it's really nothing but code to grab it from the backend.  I'm not sure if there's a way to quicken the process.  If it is due to either the backend or the code connecting to the backend I may not have any control over it, just trying some things out :)

Comment: If the problem is getting the data from the backend, you should focus the solution to your problem (and the question here) on this part. Updating the values of many labels is not a big deal (just changing the corresponding .Text properties). Your problem is retrieving the data as quickly as possible but we cannot advise on this front if we don't  know anything about that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to separate the code that retrieves the data from the database (which you do using a background thread) and the code that updates the UI (which should happen as quickly as possible because you don't want to block the UI for too long).

My suggestion would be to use the `BackgroundWorker` component to do retrieve the data for all 50 labels. When the BackgroundWorker raises the `RunWorkerCompleted` event you call the forms' `SuspendLayout` function, update all the values of the labels and then you call `ResumeLayout`. SuspendLayout stops a control from redrawing until you call ResumeLayout.

More info: [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), [SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx), [ResumeLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout.aspx)

Comment: I have tried implementing this method but am having some issues with the application crashing as soon as it hits the RunWorkerCompleted event. Is there any trace of the crash anywhere in Visual Studio where I can see what happened to cause the crash?  It was obviously due to some cross threading issue but I'm not sure where

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the RunWorkerCompleted event and step through your code.